# Bigtable emulator. Not find an appropriate constructor

Tags: java, gcloud, bigtable

Recently, I'm trying to develop something use Bigtable emulator with java(Spring Boot) on IntelliJ IDEA tool.

What I have done:

1. Bigtable emulator works well on my computer (MacOs 10.15.6).
   [image]
2. "cbt" works normally with Bigtable emulator running on my mac as somethings like [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/quickstart-cbt).

[image]
**I've checked that running Bigtable emulator doesn't need real gcloud credential.**

3. I write a unit test on IEDA like [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/samples-hbase-java-hello) works fine.
   I have added environment variable in setting like this:

[image]
My unit test code:

I. Connect init:

```
Configuration conf;
Connection connection = null;
conf = BigtableConfiguration.configure("fake-project", "fake-instance");

String host = "localhost";
String port = "8086";
```

II. Constant data going to write into table.

```
final byte[] TABLE_NAME = Bytes.toBytes("Hello-Bigtable");
final byte[] COLUMN_FAMILY_NAME = Bytes.toBytes("cf1");
final byte[] COLUMN_NAME = Bytes.toBytes("greeting");

final String[] GREETINGS = {
        "Hello World!", "Hello Cloud Bigtable!", "Hello!!"
};
```

III. Connecting:  **(Duplicated to I.Connect init.)**

```
Configuration conf;
Connection connection = null;
conf = BigtableConfiguration.configure("fake-project", "fake-instance");
String host = "localhost";
String port = "8086";
```

III. Connecting: **(Edited)**

```
if(!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(host)){
    conf.set(BigtableOptionsFactory.BIGTABLE_HOST_KEY, host);
    conf.set(BigtableOptionsFactory.BIGTABLE_PORT_KEY,port);
    conf.set(BigtableOptionsFactory.BIGTABLE_USE_PLAINTEXT_NEGOTIATION, "true");
}
connection = BigtableConfiguration.connect(conf);
```

IV. Write & Read data:

```
Admin admin = connection.getAdmin();
Table table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf(TABLE_NAME));
if(!admin.tableExists(TableName.valueOf(TABLE_NAME))){
    HTableDescriptor descriptor = new HTableDescriptor(TableName.valueOf(TABLE_NAME));
    descriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor(COLUMN_FAMILY_NAME));
    System.out.print("Create table " + descriptor.getNameAsString());
    admin.createTable(descriptor);
}
for (int i = 0; i < GREETINGS.length; i++) {
    String rowKey = "greeting" + i;

    Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(rowKey));
    put.addColumn(COLUMN_FAMILY_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, Bytes.toBytes(GREETINGS[i]));
    table.put(put);
}
Scan scan = new Scan();
ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(scan);
for (Result row : scanner) {
    byte[] valueBytes = row.getValue(COLUMN_FAMILY_NAME, COLUMN_NAME);
    System.out.println('\t' + Bytes.toString(valueBytes));
}
```

V. Output

```
    Hello World!
    Hello Cloud Bigtable!
    Hello!!
```

---

Problem came after I get this code to my project.
When I use 'debug' [image] to run the code.

I get somethings like this
when it trying to connect bigtable:
[image]
Seems that it can't new instance base on the config i create.

Eventually, it shows me an error like

```
Could not find an appropriate constructor for com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase1_x.BigtableConnection
```

P.S. I have tried to use command running IntelliJ IDEA. Reason I doing so is because I missing environment variable when I using unit test.
In my .zshrc:

[image]

My CMD tool is iTerm2 with oh-myzsh.

Anythings is help!!!!

Thanks lots.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you miss the constructor for the [BigtableConnection](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/hbase-client/javadoc/com/google/cloud/bigtable/hbase2_x/BigtableConnection#constructor-summary): `BigtableConnection(org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration conf)`

I would suggest you trying to create a `Connection` object by following the steps mentioned in [Google Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/hbase-connecting#settings-in-code)

```
private static Connection connection = null;
   
public static void connect() throws IOException {
    Configuration config = BigtableConfiguration.configure(PROJECT_ID, INSTANCE_ID);
    // Include the following line if you are using app profiles.
    // If you do not include the following line, the connection uses the
    // default app profile.
    config.set(BigtableOptionsFactory.APP_PROFILE_ID_KEY, APP_PROFILE_ID);
    connection = BigtableConfiguration.connect(config);
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer! I found that I have duplicated code in my question. The step you mention I have done it in my code @@

Comment: I have edited my question marked the duplicated code as deleted.

Comment: Maybe some of the parameters are not passed properly on `config.set()`. Could you comment the `if` statement and pass the parameters the way suggested in the above documentation?